# PHP not inserting more then 91 rows form data to data base using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image]

I am trying to insert more then 150 rows to data base but the post request is happening for only 91 rows and the console log says internal server error

After inserting 91 rows it is giving the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

MY HTML FORM

```
<form id="mySpan4" style="display: block;">
<table class="fixed_headers"><tbody>

<!-- SKIPPED TO OCC 90 Showing only 90 to 94 -->

        </tr><tr>
        <td>PRASAD  D R <input type="hidden" name="student[90]" value="PRASAD  D R"><input type="hidden" name="Reg[90]" value="13KQC31170"><input type="hidden" name="schoolid[90]" value="FT001"><input type="hidden" name="section[90]" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="standard[90]" value="III BCOM"><input type="hidden" name="Subject[90]" value="COM-42"><input type="hidden" name="date1[90]" value="16-01-07 00:00:00"><input type="hidden" name="UserType[90]" value="STUDENT"><input type="hidden" name="Userid[90]" value="admin"><input type="hidden" name="date_user_submitted[90]" value="2016-01-07  03:51:45 pm"></td>



        <td><input id="radio01[90]" name="present[90]" type="radio" value="Present"><label for="radio01[90]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio02[90]" name="present[90]" type="radio" value="Absent"><label for="radio02[90]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio03[90]" name="present[90]" type="radio" value="Leave"><label for="radio03[90]"><span></span></label></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>PRASAD K T <input type="hidden" name="student[91]" value="PRASAD K T"><input type="hidden" name="Reg[91]" value="13KQC31171"><input type="hidden" name="schoolid[91]" value="FT001"><input type="hidden" name="section[91]" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="standard[91]" value="III BCOM"><input type="hidden" name="Subject[91]" value="COM-42"><input type="hidden" name="date1[91]" value="16-01-07 00:00:00"><input type="hidden" name="UserType[91]" value="STUDENT"><input type="hidden" name="Userid[91]" value="admin"><input type="hidden" name="date_user_submitted[91]" value="2016-01-07  03:51:45 pm"></td>



        <td><input id="radio01[91]" name="present[91]" type="radio" value="Present"><label for="radio01[91]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio02[91]" name="present[91]" type="radio" value="Absent"><label for="radio02[91]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio03[91]" name="present[91]" type="radio" value="Leave"><label for="radio03[91]"><span></span></label></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>PRASANNA B <input type="hidden" name="student[92]" value="PRASANNA B"><input type="hidden" name="Reg[92]" value="13KQC31172"><input type="hidden" name="schoolid[92]" value="FT001"><input type="hidden" name="section[92]" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="standard[92]" value="III BCOM"><input type="hidden" name="Subject[92]" value="COM-42"><input type="hidden" name="date1[92]" value="16-01-07 00:00:00"><input type="hidden" name="UserType[92]" value="STUDENT"><input type="hidden" name="Userid[92]" value="admin"><input type="hidden" name="date_user_submitted[92]" value="2016-01-07  03:51:45 pm"></td>



        <td><input id="radio01[92]" name="present[92]" type="radio" value="Present"><label for="radio01[92]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio02[92]" name="present[92]" type="radio" value="Absent"><label for="radio02[92]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio03[92]" name="present[92]" type="radio" value="Leave"><label for="radio03[92]"><span></span></label></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>PRASANNAKUMAR K <input type="hidden" name="student[93]" value="PRASANNAKUMAR K"><input type="hidden" name="Reg[93]" value="13KQC31173"><input type="hidden" name="schoolid[93]" value="FT001"><input type="hidden" name="section[93]" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="standard[93]" value="III BCOM"><input type="hidden" name="Subject[93]" value="COM-42"><input type="hidden" name="date1[93]" value="16-01-07 00:00:00"><input type="hidden" name="UserType[93]" value="STUDENT"><input type="hidden" name="Userid[93]" value="admin"><input type="hidden" name="date_user_submitted[93]" value="2016-01-07  03:51:45 pm"></td>



        <td><input id="radio01[93]" name="present[93]" type="radio" value="Present"><label for="radio01[93]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio02[93]" name="present[93]" type="radio" value="Absent"><label for="radio02[93]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio03[93]" name="present[93]" type="radio" value="Leave"><label for="radio03[93]"><span></span></label></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>PREETHI C R <input type="hidden" name="student[94]" value="PREETHI C R"><input type="hidden" name="Reg[94]" value="13KQC31175"><input type="hidden" name="schoolid[94]" value="FT001"><input type="hidden" name="section[94]" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="standard[94]" value="III BCOM"><input type="hidden" name="Subject[94]" value="COM-42"><input type="hidden" name="date1[94]" value="16-01-07 00:00:00"><input type="hidden" name="UserType[94]" value="STUDENT"><input type="hidden" name="Userid[94]" value="admin"><input type="hidden" name="date_user_submitted[94]" value="2016-01-07  03:51:45 pm"></td>



        <td><input id="radio01[94]" name="present[94]" type="radio" value="Present"><label for="radio01[94]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio02[94]" name="present[94]" type="radio" value="Absent"><label for="radio02[94]"><span></span></label></td>
        <td><input id="radio03[94]" name="present[94]" type="radio" value="Leave"><label for="radio03[94]"><span></span></label></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>RADHA H N <input type="hidden" name="student[95]" value="RADHA H N"><input type="hidden" name="Reg[95]" value="13KQC31179"><input type="hidden" name="schoolid[95]" value="FT001"><input type="hidden" name="section[95]" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="standard[95]" value="III BCOM"><input type="hidden" name="Subject[95]" value="COM-42"><input type="hidden" name="date1[95]" value="16-01-07 00:00:00"><input type="hidden" name="UserType[95]" value="STUDENT"><input type="hidden" name="Userid[95]" value="admin"><input type="hidden" name="date_user_submitted[95]" value="2016-01-07  03:51:45 pm"></td>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#mySpan4').submit(function(e) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'http://localhost/demo_TeacherApp/attendence_submit.php',   // you should not use absolute addresses, with http:// . only relative paths
                        data: $('#mySpan4').serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            // log $sql string
                            //<!-- $('#log').html(data); -->
                        }
                    });
                    // prevents the form from really submitting through the normal way
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                })
            });
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "xxxx";

    $dbname = "xxxxx";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // ** insert data in to data base ** //
    $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_master (StudentFirstName,AttendanceStatus,StudentRegID,SchoolID,Section,Standard,Subjects,AttendanceDate,UserType,Attendence_taken_by,Attendence_taken_date) VALUES ";
    // **hear the data or is calculated using student as a string the number of student names are passed the same number of data is inserted in to data base ** //
    foreach($_POST['Reg']  as $i=>$student) {

        // ** so the data is inserted in to data base   ** //
        $sql .= sprintf("%s ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
        , ($i==0 ? '' : ',')  
        // **  data from Ajax   ** //
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['student'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['present'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Reg'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['schoolid'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['section'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['standard'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Subject'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['date1'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['UserType'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Userid'][$i]))
        , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['date_user_submitted'][$i]))

        );
    }
    // ** on success full function   ** //
    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        echo $sql;// **can do any thing to recognise if the data is inserted if this gives the out put then the data is shorly inserted in to data base  ** //
    }

?>
```

Comment: **Show us the ACTUAL error message**, then possbly we can help!

Comment: Think you might be missing a trick here - use prepared statements rather than a massively concatenated string

Comment: My thoughts entirely @RamRaider prepare the statement with parameters once and then execute that prepared statement any number of times. This will reduce the execution time of your queries as the query will only need to be _compiled and optimized_ once. You are using `mysqli_` but getting none of its benefits

Comment: @RayonDabre am doing this for the attendence purpose if there are 200 students i need to insert 200 rows to data base in my case now i have 150 students and it is not inserting

Comment: Have you hit a server default transfer size limit? Use a tool like Fiddler2 to see what is going on and show us the real error :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie wat about php how to load in fiddle there is no option

Comment: i have posted the console error image

Comment: Fiddler2 is a HTTP comms inspection  tool... not JSFiddle! :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie am not able to do that if u want i can share my screen to any one am ok with it the jsfiddle want accept PHP code

Comment: Ok thats a start. Now show us a few lines from the servers `php error log` as this might be more useful

Comment: @RiggsFolly after inserting 91 rows it is giving `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that in your HTML your indexing jumps from occurance 92 to occurance 146.

Also the hidden fields that for `PRASANNA B` have occurance 92 but the radio buttons have occurance 145.

This looks like when you create this form something has gone wrong with your indexing stratagy! This would possibly explain why it all starts to go wrong when loading row 92 to your database

```
</tr><tr>
<td>PRASANNA B <input type="hidden" name="student[92]" value="PRASANNA B"><input type="hidden" name="Reg[92]" value="13KQC31172"><input type="hidden" name="schoolid[92]" value="FT001"><input type="hidden" name="section[92]" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="standard[92]" value="III BCOM"><input type="hidden" name="Subject[92]" value="COM-38"><input type="hidden" name="date1[92]" value="16-01-07 00:00:00"><input type="hidden" name="UserType[92]" value="STUDENT"><input type="hidden" name="Userid[92]" value="admin"><input type="hidden" name="date_user_submitted[92]" value="2016-01-07  03:37:22 pm"></td>

<td><input id="radio01[145]" name="present[145]" type="radio" value="Present"><label for="radio01[145]"><span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio02[145]" name="present[145]" type="radio" value="Absent"><label for="radio02[145]"><span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio03[145]" name="present[145]" type="radio" value="Leave"><label for="radio03[145]"><span></span></label></td>
</tr><tr>
```

***Ok now we have disproved that idea!*** Lets start at the beginning.

PHP has a couple of parameters that might be getting exceeded i.e.

- post_max_size *Which would mean that not all the post array was being received by the script*
- max_input_vars *Which limits the number of `<input>` variables that will be accepted by a script*

As you have at least **1950** input variable that I know of this may be the first one to check. So look at your `php.ini` file for both of these parameter and let me know what they are.

**So from your comment** it seems like `max_input_vars = 1000` is not enough for this script which has at least **1950** variables. This would definitely explain the error you are getting! 1000 being the default I believe which is why its in comment form.

So amend the `php.ini` and make `max_input_vars = 2500`, just to be on the safe side without the `;` comment of course.

**Dont forget** to restart Apache after you have made the change to `php.ini`

Comment: this makes sense thaks for ur support vl investigate on it a moment

Comment: Well spotted - it would be good to see how the form is generated initially ~ there is a spurious closing `</tr>` tag right after the opening `tbody` tag

Comment: @RiggsFolly as i mentioned above as i coudnet post all the html code so i deleted some of it that is not the issue

Comment: Ok so edit your question and make sure that the HTML you post is accurate for occurance 90 throught 94

Comment: See additional info in the answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly am sorry for late reply `memory_limit = 256M` `post_max_size = 828M`  this is in comment mode `; max_input_vars = 1000`

Comment: @RiggsFolly am not using apache am using iis

Comment: Ok, I assume you are then FastCGI so a restart is probably not required unless you get the crash in the same place which would indicate that it has not picked up the parameter change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100045/discussion-between-shaik-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: the issue was with this  `max_input_vars = 2500`

Comment: the data is inserted but still it is giving me `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: You may need to ask another question as that sounds like something you are doing after the database has been updated. Maybe what you are trying to send back to the client. I will look out for the new question

Comment: i my self solved the issue thanks for your support much needed

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that you have reached the max POST size then this won't help, but as an example of using prepared statements to insert the data this should be useful. Using the form data that you posted on Pastebin in conjunction with this code it inserted it happily inserted 151 rows into the db with no errors ( yes, created a table specially ) ~ perhaps I should add that I submitted the form via POST without ajax!

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        function filter( $conn, $var ){
            return $conn->real_escape_string( filter_var( $var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
        }

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "xxxx";
        $dbname = "xxxxx";
        $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
        /* I obviously used correct details for my db */

        $sql='INSERT INTO `attendance_master` ( 
                `StudentFirstName`, `AttendanceStatus`, `StudentRegID`, `SchoolID`, `Section`, 
                `Standard`, `Subjects`, `AttendanceDate`, `UserType`, `Attendence_taken_by`, `Attendence_taken_date`
            ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )';

        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );


        foreach( $_POST['Reg']  as $i => $student ) {
            try{
                $stud   = filter( $conn, $_POST['student'][$i] );
                $pres   = filter( $conn, $_POST['present'][$i] );
                $reg    = filter( $conn, $_POST['Reg'][$i] );
                $id     = filter( $conn, $_POST['schoolid'][$i] );
                $sect   = filter( $conn, $_POST['section'][$i] );
                $stan   = filter( $conn, $_POST['standard'][$i] );
                $subj   = filter( $conn, $_POST['Subject'][$i] );
                $date   = filter( $conn, $_POST['date1'][$i] );
                $type   = filter( $conn, $_POST['UserType'][$i] );
                $uid    = filter( $conn, $_POST['Userid'][$i] );
                $subm   = filter( $conn, $_POST['date_user_submitted'][$i] );

                $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', $stud, $pres, $reg, $id, $sect, $stan, $subj, $date, $type, $uid, $subm );
                if( !$stmt->execute() ) throw new Exception( 'Insert failed @ row'.$i, 400 );
            } catch( Exception $e ){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                continue;
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: that indicates the data type being passed in at that position in the sql statement. `s` - string, `i` - integer. Similar to what you have done in the `sprintf` function call except without the `%` sign

Comment: i tried again it is just inserting 91 rows the remaining it dint

Comment: Even though this was not the actual error, do keep using this style of parameterised and prepared queries as is also provides sql injection protection, and when used to execute the same query more than once will speed up you script execution time.